# ¿Android studio se actualizo y tiene problemas para "correr" las apps?

Tags: android-studio, ide, update

hace unos días actualice Android Studio, se descargaron las actualizaciones, se instalaron correctamente, todo bien pero al correr el app presenta errores:

aveces este

```
  Failed to find byte code for javax/naming/spi/ObjectFactory
```

o avaces este

```
  Failed to find byte code for javax/transaction/xa/XAResource
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea para corregir por favor

Comment: Ya intentaste Clean-Project y Rebulid Project?

Comment: Clean proyect - ok , rebuild project - Failed to find byte code for javax/naming/spi/ObjectFactory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Al parecer existe un bug en la actualización Android Studio ver. 3.1., esto cuando se tiene habilitado `Instant Run`,

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/72811718

en mi caso yo he actualizado sin problemas pero no tengo en una versión anterior habilitado `Instant Run`, deshabilita `Instant Run` en tu Android Studio con esto debe funcionar:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: de nuevo muchas gracias la guru del android... ya funciona....

Comment: un placer ayudar, saludos!