# Codigo sobre ImageView en android

Tags: android

Hola buenas noches necesito de su ayuda con un código que es realizado en android studio versión 3.4.1 API 21:android 5 (LOLLIPOP) en donde esta una imagen en pantalla junto con un botón y cuando se presione el botón,que muestre la imagen se actualizará por otra la cual cuando cuando es ejecutado se presenta el mensaje de que se detuvo.
les dejo adjunto el código  espero su pronta respuesta ante mano gracias.

```
MainAcivity.xml

package c.java.imagen;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void dog (View view) {

        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.dogimageView);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.dog1);

        Log.i("Test", "Button clicked");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**** Activity_main.xml****

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dogimageView"
        android:layout_width="378dp"
        android:layout_height="354dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="18dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:onClick="dog"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.489"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/dog" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="170dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="153dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="278dp"
        android:text="@string/boton"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="146dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="430dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

***LOGCAT***

```
07-22 07:36:36.209 19283-19283/? E/Zygote: v2
07-22 07:36:36.209 19283-19283/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD checking this for 10310
07-22 07:36:36.209 19283-19283/? I/libpersona: KNOX_SDCARD not a persona
07-22 07:36:36.209 19283-19283/? W/SELinux: Function: selinux_compare_spd_ram, index[1], priority [2], priority version is VE=SEPF_SECMOBILE_6.0.1_0031
07-22 07:36:36.219 19283-19283/? E/Zygote: accessInfo : 0
07-22 07:36:36.219 19283-19283/? W/SELinux: SELinux: seapp_context_lookup: seinfo=default, level=s0:c512,c768, pkgname=c.java.imagen 
07-22 07:36:36.219 19283-19283/? I/art: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
07-22 07:36:36.259 19283-19283/c.java.imagen D/TimaKeyStoreProvider: TimaSignature is unavailable
07-22 07:36:36.259 19283-19283/c.java.imagen D/ActivityThread: Added TimaKeyStore provider
07-22 07:36:36.279 19283-19283/c.java.imagen D/ResourcesManager: For user 0 new overlays fetched Null
07-22 07:36:36.349 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:36.559 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:36.629 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:36.689 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:36.759 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:36.829 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:36.899 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:36.969 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:37.029 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:37.109 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:37.169 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/c.java.imagen-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@c.java.imagen-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
07-22 07:36:37.179 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/c.java.imagen-1/lib/arm
07-22 07:36:37.179 19283-19283/c.java.imagen I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-22 07:36:37.289 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
07-22 07:36:37.359 19283-19283/c.java.imagen I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
07-22 07:36:37.359 19283-19283/c.java.imagen I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>
07-22 07:36:37.439 19283-19283/c.java.imagen D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
07-22 07:36:37.439 19283-19283/c.java.imagen D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
07-22 07:36:37.439 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060057 (t=5 e=87) (error -75)
07-22 07:36:37.439 19283-19283/c.java.imagen W/ResourceType: Failure getting entry for 0x7f060057 (t=5 e=87) (error -75)
07-22 07:36:37.439 19283-19283/c.java.imagen D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
07-22 07:36:37.449 19283-19283/c.java.imagen E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: c.java.imagen, PID: 19283
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{c.java.imagen/c.java.imagen.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140)
        at c.java.imagen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class ImageView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:794)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at c.java.imagen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f060057
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:2596)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.loadDrawableFromDelegates(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:331)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:198)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:191)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:102)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:59)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:78)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:68)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createImageView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:182)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:106)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:758)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:847) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:527) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:469) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:140) 
        at c.java.imagen.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:24) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) 
07-22 07:36:40.029 19283-19283/c.java.imagen I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19283 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Yo no veo ningún problema. ¿podrías mostrar el seguimiento(StackTrace) para entender mejor el problema?

Comment: el codigo corre y se instala bien pero en vez de abrir la app sale se detuvo y quiero que me ayuden con ese inconveniente que tengo.

Comment: Tienes que abrir el logcat y pegarnos el código de error que aparece sin eso es complicado encontrar el error.

Comment: Hola @soraya edite tu pregunta, es un poco extraño el error que presentas, te sugiero deshabilitar el "Instant Run", saludos.

Comment: esta deshabilitado el instant run

Answer (score 1):

El problema radica en que has colocado el método:  `android:onClick="dog"` en la etiqueta de la `ImageView` y  deberia ir en `Button`, Por tal motivo no hay cambios al presionar el boton, una vez echo los cambios la App se ejecuta con normalidad.

Comment: Hola Santiago, el método "dog", también puede ser llamado desde un ImageView, saludos.

Comment: Si, pero el dice que se realiza al presionar el botón y no la imagen.

Comment: Si presiona el botón simplemente no realizará ninguna acción. Es un poco extraño en realidad el problema que presenta.

Answer (score 0):

El problema se presenta al "inflar" el ImageView y la razón es que un recurso que intenta cargar no existe.

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9:
>   Error inflating class ImageView   Caused by:
>   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID
>   0x7f060057

En este indica que  un recurso es el que intentas cargar no existe.

Lo extraño es que si no existiera el recurso definido en tu .xml no permitiría una compilación.

Por otro lado la llamada al método `dog` mediante `android:onClick="dog"` también se permite llamar desde un `ImageView`.

Ahora también tienes este mensaje de error:

> starting instant run server: is main process Before Android 4.1,
>   method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter
>   androidx.vectordrawable.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter,
>   android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode)
>   would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in
>   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable

**Te sugiero como solución entonces que deshabilites el `Instant Run`**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Revisa esta respuesta:

[¿Android studio se actualizo y tiene problemas para "correr" las apps?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154627/android-studio-se-actualizo-y-tiene-problemas-para-correr-las-apps/154679#154679)